# Access variable in main node file from an imported file

Tags: node.js

```
//in app.js
var x = require("x.js");
var instanceX = new x();
require("./Weather")();


//in Weather.js
instanceX.getName();
```

In this case instanceX wouldn't exist when referenced from Weather.js. How do I make instanceX accessible in Weather.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to approach this in module design.  One simple way is to just pass the variable to the weather.js constructor:

```
//in app.js
var x = require("x.js");
var instanceX = new x();
require("./Weather")(instanceX);


//in Weather.js
var instanceX;
module.exports = function(ix) {
    instanceX = ix;
}

// then elsewhere in the module
instanceX.getName();
```

I refer to this as the "push" model because you're pushing things to the module that you want to share with it.